# Can I use urlllib2 to play videos?

Tags: python, urllib

Can I use `urllib2` to open a webpage which contain video (like vimeo page) and this visit will be counted as view?

Comment: That depends very much on how the web page counts views. You will need to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: Youtube Count system for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes. A request done with `urllib2` will be a normal HTTP request and as such will be recognized as a normal “visit” for the server you are connecting to. Depending on what additional headers you set, you can even make yourself look like a common browser, so they won’t be able to filter you out either.

As far as video counts go however, I’m pretty sure that simply visiting the site—without executing any code on it, and without actually *playing* the video—will not increase the view counter. In addition, these sites employ some systems to prevent abuse of the counter too. So if you have the hope to be able to spoof real views and increment the view counter by repeatedly visiting the page, then you will be out of luck.

As for actually playing—if you are interested in the content instead of the view counter—then yes, you can use Python to get access to the video. Of course Python won’t be able to play it, but you can download it instead. There are scripts like [this one](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) that already do this for you too.

Comment: Aside from the technical methods employed to prevent you from doing so, I'm pretty sure scripting to increase views is a direct violation of most TOS for video hosting sites (since views affects so much on the site - in the case of YouTube followers/views affects monetization as well, so this could be outright theft/fraud).